# Reading a Secure XML from Google-App-Engine in Xcode (iOS)

Tags: xcode, security, google-app-engine

I have a Google-App-Engine website written in Java on which I am storing an XML file, and an iOS app which needs to read that file. However, it is very important that this XML cannot be viewed by anyone else. I've been looking into some possibilities, but have had some issues.

I've mainly been trying to add a security constraint in my Java project's web.xml such as this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/file.xml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This works fine for me when I'm trying to access the file from a web browser. I'm redirected to a login page where I can enter username and password. But inside the app, I don't know where to enter this information. Trying to get the file returns the source code of the Google login page. So how does one access these files?

I also tried to use the ASIHTTPRequest classes, and set:

```
[request setUsername:@"username"];
[request setPassword:@"password"];
```

But still, I end up with the login page's source code. Should I look into using CFCredentials? Or is there a much simpler solution that I am missing?

I know I could also manually encrypt the file and then decrypt it in the app, but it's a pretty large XML and so I would prefer not having to do that.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The page is secured by Google account logging (and on top of that the user needs to be an admin of the application), you need to set a login cookie in order to be allowed to enter.

The only example that I know of setting the login cookie from a [mobile app is Nick's blog](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app) which implements the login using Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/). It's accessible from Google App Engine, and via an [experimental JSON API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/), would be accessible from iOS as well.

You can specify ACLs for files you've uploaded to Google Cloud Storage, so that only a limited set of users can access them. Authorization to access those files is handled via OAuth 2.